# multipart/form-data Invocation issues

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, jax-rs, resteasy

Trying to invoke a POST request which accepts multipart/form-data

*Generate Client using the swagger code gen with following config options*

```
<configOptions>
    <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
    <sourceFolder>src/main/java</sourceFolder>                              
    <invokerPackage>com.x.client.autogen.y</invokerPackage>
</configOptions>
 <output>target/generated-sources</output>
  <environmentVariables>
   <library>resteasy</library>
   </environmentVariables>
</configuration>
```

*POM has resteasy-multipart-provider added as dependency*

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.7.Final</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Now I invoke the request as

```
ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
        apiClient.setBasePath("http://x/getOutput");                
        apiClient.setUsername("u");
        apiClient.setPassword("u");
        DefaultApi api = new DefaultApi(apiClient);
        try {
            String response = api.getOutput("response", xml.concat(";type=application/xml"), "transactionId");

        } catch (Throwable e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This throws an error :

```
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: could not find writer for content-type multipart/form-data type: java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

**However**

*When i invoke using the below snippet- the request goes through - It also tries to find the provider and Gets the Provider*

```
MultipartFormDataOutput mpfdo = new MultipartFormDataOutput();
        mpfdo.addFormData("InputData", xml, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);
        mpfdo.addFormData("Destination", "response", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);
        mpfdo.addFormData("TransactionId", "TransactionId", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);
        Entity.entity(mpfdo, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);

        Response response = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("http://x/getOutput")
                .register(new BasicAuthentication("u", "u"))
                .request().header("Accept", MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE)
                .post(Entity.entity(mpfdo, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE));
```

I am using **spring-boot:run** to run the entier application

So RestEnpoint -> Service -> Service Invokes the Client Enpoint